# CEF Python Hide Browser

Tags: python, chromium-embedded, cefpython

I create a Browser:

`browser = cef.CreateBrowserSync(url=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+'\\gui.html', window_title="Title")`

Is there any way to hide and show the window whenever I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the "wxpython.py" example then you can call `MainFrame.Hide()` to hide window and `Show()` to show it.

If using the "hello_world.py" example then you would need to make a native OS call using for example ctypes. For Windows the code would be:

```py
import ctypes
SW_SHOW = 5
SW_HIDE = 0
hwnd = browser.GetWindowHandle()
ctypes.windll.user32.ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_HIDE)
ctypes.windll.user32.ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW)
```